# Function name in setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a page in a MVC app that uses `setInterval` for firing a JavaScript function, calling it by its name. There are several buttons and links that, when the user clicks them, they make ajax calls to the database. Not just that, it also clears the interval and sets another function to be run (each button and link has its own function). This is not functioning properly and I would need to find out the name of the function being run by `setInterval`. The debugger gives me the ID, but that's not very useful. Can I see the function's name, for debugging purposes only?

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
var Abc = Abc || {

    myInterval: '',
    refreshTime: 120000,

    init: function () {
        $("#button1").click(function () {
            Abc.function1();
            clearInterval(Abc.myInterval);
            Abc.myInterval = setInterval(Abc.function1, Abc.refreshTime);
        });
        $("#button2").click(function () {  
            Abc.function2();
            clearInterval(Abc.myInterval);
            Abc.myInterval = setInterval(Abc.function2, Abc.refreshTime);  
        });
    },

    function1: function () {
        $.ajax({
            // Code
        });
    },
    function2: function () {
        $.ajax({
            // Code
        });
    },
}
```

What I need is `function1`, `function2`...

Thanks!!

Comment: That's a neat parrot you've got there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a named function, like

```
function1: function function1() {
//                  ^^^^^^^^^
    $.ajax({
        // Code
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line to each function:

```
console.info('<functionname> is running');
```

You would replace  with the name of the function, of course.